# Working in team on same drupal 7 site (local)

Tags: git, drupal, version-control, bitbucket, collaboration

I would like to know if there are some ways where you can work on a same Drupal website locally with several people. Is there some way to push everything on git or bit bucket, without having bugs? I can imagine that the DB needs to be updated every time someone pushes.

Are there suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If Drupal site's module and theme files already live in code, you can manage those in Git without any extra tools.
See more here - https://www.drupal.org/node/803746

Answer (score 1):

Both answers until now are fine. Your team can also use drush to help get things more confortable and safe. The module 'Features' can help a lot depending of your workflow. There's some tips: https://www.acquia.com/blog/using-git-drush-win-workflow

If you need a local private repo management system 'a la' github (repo browser, diff tool, key management, repo permissions etc.), consider using gitlab. But git itself can suit most of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deploy some changes that you've made in DB use https://www.drupal.org/project/features and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.
And push code as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Or Pantheon has a really cool multi-dev app